# Mostrar elementos en select option basados en una selección de otro select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

estoy aprendiendo php para wordpress y tengo un problemilla.

Tengo dos tablas, una llamada wp_menu_do y otra wp_menu_category. wp_menu_do muestra denominaciones de origen de vino, y wp_menu_category muestra el tipo de vino (blanco o tinto).

Con el código que muestro abajo, obtengo en un select el tipo de vino y en el otro su denominación de origen. Si despliego el select, muestra bien las denominaciones de ese tipo de vino. Hasta ahí bien. Lo que quiero es que si el usuario modifica el select del tipo de vino, se cargen en el otro sus denominaciones de origen.
Como muestro en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$items_cat_dos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wdo.id_do, wdo.name_do, wdo.id_category, wmc.id, wmc.name
                      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}menu_do AS wdo JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}menu_category AS wmc ON (wdo.id_category = wmc.id)");

foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo '<form method="POST" name="form_update" style="display:inline" id="menu_form_'.$item->id.'">' . 

<select class="itemcategory cat_wines" id="cat_wines" name="cat_wines" data-menu-id="'.$item->id_category.'">';
    foreach ($items_cat as $item_cat) {
        echo '<option value="'.$item_cat->id.'" '.(($item_cat->id==$item->id_category)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$item_cat->name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>' .
    '<select class="itemcategory cat_do" id="cat_do" name="cat_do" data-menu-id="'.$item->id_category.'">';
                foreach ($items_cat_dos as $item_cat_do) {
                    if($item_cat_do->id_category===$item->id_category) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$item_cat_do->id_do.'" '.(($item_cat_do->id_do==$item->id_do)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'
                            .$item_cat_do->name_do.
                        '</option>';
                    }
                }
        echo '</select>' .
</form>';
    }
```

Llevo dándole vueltas varios días y nada, he leído que se hace con ajax, tengo la siguiente función en un archivo js.

```
$(document).on('change', '.cat_wines', function(e) {

    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val() + ' and text ' + $(this).text() + ' was selected.');});
```

Con el alert sé que entra bien al cambiar el option select, y pasa el valor del option bien, pero ya no sé que hacer aquí, no tengo ni idea de ajax.

Si pudiera orientarme alguien le estaría muy agradecido. He probado esta solución de este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option pero al estar dentro de un foreach sólo lo hace con el primer elemento del foreach. ¿alguien me ayuda?

Muchas gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, deberes realizarlo mediante AJAX.
Debería quedarte algo parecido a esto en el js:

```
$('.cat_wines').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_que_devuelve_DO.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
           id_vino: $(this).val()
        },
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (respuesta) {
            console.log('Error: ' + respuesta);
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            $('#cat_do').empty();
            for (var i in respuesta) {
                $('#cat_do').append('<option value="' + respuesta[i].id_do + '">' + respuesta[i].id_do + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Cada vez que realices un cambio en el primer select, vaciará el segundo y lo rellenara con los resultados que le devuelva el PHP.
Todo eso de forma asíncrona, gracias a AJAX. Recuerda hacer que el PHP devuelva un JSON únicamente con los datos para de las DO.

Comment: La segunda select se borra con cada iteración del bucle `for` por lo que al final sólo habrá una opción (la última del array). Además, la variable `json` no es nada, debería ser `respuesta` (también en el bucle `for`)

Comment: Bien visto, de todas formas, no está probado ni nada, era por ponerlo como ejemplo.